# What does the symbol $\stackrel{!}{=}$ in the context of quaternions mean?

Tags: notation, physics, quaternions

I was reading "Physics from Symmetry" by Jakob Schwichtenberg recently. And in part 3 of chapter 3, he goes over quaternions and I found the following statement: 
The set of *unit* quaternions $q = a\textbf{1} + b\textbf{i} + c\textbf{j} +d\textbf{k}$ satisfy the condition
$$q^{\dagger}q \stackrel{!}{=} 1$$
Where, $q^\dagger = (q^{*})^T$ 
What does the symbol $\stackrel{!}{=}$ mean?

Comment: That's not common notation but it seems the author is making a distinction between an implied equality and one that defines a property. The characterization of unit quaternions you describe holds just as well if you replaced that with an ordinary equal sign.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks @j0equ1nn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means “should be equal”, i.e. this is a condition being imposed, rather than an equation that holds generally. It’s not specific to the context of quaternions.

Comment: All right, thank @joriki!