# Is there a symbol for "cannot equal to"?

Tags: notation

I know $\overset{!}{=}$ means "must be equal to." Would it be reasonable to conclude that $\overset{!}{\neq}$ means "must be equal to anything but", i.e. "cannot equal to"?

###### References:

1. [Notation for “should be equal to”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926403/notation-for-should-be-equal-to)
2. [Must be equal and other stacked math symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/must-be-equal-and-other-stacked-math-symbols)
3. [What does ! above = mean [closed]](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11077/what-does-above-mean)

Comment: I have never seen the notation you refer to .  Please provide a reference.

Comment: I have never seen this notation before today, but it does appear here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597085

Comment: I have mostly just seen $=$ used for this, but that symbol is overloaded, so introducing $\stackrel{!}{=}$ isn't entirely a bad idea. Some people use $:=$ for definitions, this seems like the same idea.

Comment: I use $\stackrel{!}{=}$ to emphasise surprise or enthusiasm when it would otherwise cause confusion to use $!$ on the RHS. The same goes for $\stackrel{!}{\neq}$ or even $\stackrel{!}{\le}$. What I'm getting at, I suppose, is that the notation doesn't have to be mathematical in nature.

Comment: @lulu Done. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: None of those citations really back up the meaning you wish.  I do not believe this is a widely recognized notation for what you want.  I don't even think it's mathematical notation...maybe pedagogical.  As a couple of your references suggest, if I saw it I'd be inclined to read it as "Though you really don't expect this, the left hand is equal to the right!"

Comment: @Shaun: I've also used "$\stackrel{!}{=}$" for surprise or enthusiasm. (For instance, I might start a trig identity proof with "$\stackrel{?}{=}$", and end with "$\stackrel{!}{=}$".) Annoyingly, many programming languages take "`!=`" to mean "is not equal to", turning the symbol for emphasis into one of negation. Moreover, some of those same languages are such that particular a variable `x` might be "nil" vs storing an actual value, and have introduced the notation `x!` as an assurance of an actual value ... effectively restoring the emphatic nature of "!" (ie, "`x` is really there!"). Fun!